# Notifications Dropdown not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Following is my code to show the notification list on clicking the icon. But the dropdown of notifications list is not showing. As for the CSS there is only bootstrap added. Following attached is my HTML and JavaScript with mock method.

```js
function getMessageNotificationsDetails() {
  $("#messageNotificationsDetails").html("");
  $("#messageNotificationsDetails").append("<li><p class='red'>You have 5 new messages</p></li>");
  $("#messageNotificationsDetails").append("<li><p class='red'>You have 6 new messages</p></li>");

}

function getNotificationsDetails() {
  $("#notificationsDetails").html("");
  $("#notificationsDetails").append("<li><p class='red'>You have 5 new messages</p></li>");
  $("#notificationsDetails").append("<li><p class='red'>You have 56 new messages</p></li>");

}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-1 text-center text-md-right">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="notification">
        <i style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getMessageNotificationsDetails()" class="fa fa-envelope-o">
                                                </i>
        <span id="messageCount" class="badge"></span>
        <ul id="messageNotificationsDetails" class="notification-menu">
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="notification">
        <i style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="getNotificationsDetails()" class="fa fa-bell-o">
                                                </i>
        <span id="notificationsCount" class="badge"></span>
        <ul id="notificationsDetails" class="notification-menu">

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see 2 problems.

1. `unreadMessageCount` is undefined
2. Each time you use `.html()` you are overwriting the html content of the element.  It will work in your case because the last call has content in it.

Also, where and when the script is defined will affect whether or not it is available to the markup.  In your case, it needs to be defined before the markup.  You could attach the listeners via JS, and then it could run after the markup is rendered.

Comment: Oh sorry! I have created the mock method over here i know its going to be .append() also this unreadMessageCount is initialized by SignalR.

Comment: Then there is probably a different problem in the surrounding code.  When I tried your code, it worked as long as I initialized `unreadMessageCount`

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the issue. It was related to data-toggle. I wasn't toggling to show and hide in my code.